# Scons - Stop cleaning .obj files generated, on cleaning static library

Tags: scons

Using Scons, if I build static library, Scons compile all the source file and .obj files are generated. Now when I want to clean static library, I don't want to clean .obj files, how do I do that?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the background to your question? Why exactly do you need this setup, where the .obj files are kept...just as if they are the actual targets, and not the static lib? After all, you can "clean" the static lib with a simple "rm -f libtarget.*" and get what you want without SCons being involved at all...

Comment: Thaks for your reply. I am using Scons build environment to build the project. My final target is dependent on a static library and now if I try to clean my final target, the dependent static library also gets cleaned, which I don't want to, as after cleaning my final target every time I build my final target this dependent static library also gets build which I don't want. I want to clean only the files involved my final target rather than files involved in static library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
env = Environment() 
sources = ['tridip.c', 'tridip1.c', 'tridip2.c']
objects = [ env.StaticObject(sf) for sf in sources ]
env.NoClean(objects)
lib = env.StaticLibrary('tridip', objecst) 
exe = env.Program('tridip3.c', LIBS=lib, LIBPATH='.')
```

Comment: That works absolutely fine. Do you have any ide how to compile a '.k' file, like 'tridip4.k'. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: Like sources = ['tridip.c', 'tridip1.c', 'tridip2.c', 'tridip4.k']. I have checked and I get the following error "While building `['tridip4.obj']' from `['tridip4.k']': Don't know how to build from a source file with suffix `.k'"

Comment: I'm not sure what a .k file is. Can you pastebin it somewhere and post a link?

Comment: Well, I sort out '.k' compilation issue and I really don't require to compile those. Now, I want NoClean() to work only for some mentioned alias and not for all . I will put my code below:

Comment: env = Environment()
src1 = ['tridip.c', 'tridip1.c', 'tridip2.c']
obj1 = [ env.StaticObject(sf) for sf in src1 ]
lib = env.Library('tridip', obj1)
Alias('lib', lib)
src2 = ['tridip3.c']
exe = Program(src2, LIBS=lib, LIBPATH='.')
NoClean(exe, obj1)
Alias('exe', exe) . In this example, I don't want to clean obj1 when I want to build for alias 'exe' like scons -c exe but I want to clean when I build for alias 'lib' like scons -c lib - this time also it doesnot clean. So is there any logic where I can differentiate in alias or targets.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your final target and your static lib to actually depend on each other, you can create them in two separate SConstructs (two SCons projects). Like this, you'll still be able to reference the library as input to your final application/executable by name...but there will be no direct dependency detected by SCons, meaning that the static lib won't get created automatically when you try to create your final target. You'd have to do this manually each time. This is the crucial point here: you either want a dependency lib->exe, or not. In the former case, the dependency also holds for cleaning a target (and implicitly all of its dependencies further down the tree).

A way out of this dilemma would be to use the NoClean() function (see the UserGuide at http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ), but you'd have to wrap each single object file with it. Consequences are unclear regarding the correctness and stability of your build, so I definitely don't encourage you to go this way...nor any other user reading this. ;)

Comment: Well, I cannot change the flow of dependency, that's sad. Ya I am looking on NoClean() function, using which I can restrict cleaning the static lib file but I also want to restrict cleaning .obj file which I want to restrict as well which I am not able to, any idea?

Comment: Not without you showing us your current SConstructs/SConscripts in a MWE first...

Comment: env = Environment()
lib = env.StaticLibrary('tridip', ['tridip.c', 'tridip1.c', 'tridip2.c'])
NoClean(lib)
exe = Program('tridip3.c', LIBS=lib, LIBPATH='.')
NoClean(exe)

Comment: In the above comment. I am creating an .exe linking .lib. Now I am able to clean .lib and .exe, but I want to clean the intermediate .obj files. Yes I am able to clean .obj one by one. But do you have a better idea please help.

Comment: Well, I am surprised to see that although NoClean() function doesnot clean output files and .obj files but if I re-build the target, it again builds all the output files and .obj files.